# Displaying Variables in Buttons?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript and am attempting to make a simple maths game.

I'm holding the correct answer to my randomly generated maths questions in a variable named correctAnswer. I would like the value of this variable to be displayed in a button - so that when the user clicks it, they see a "Well done!" message.

This is what I've got so far - just the code to create my random questions:

```
var firstNumber;
var secondNumber;
var correctAnswer;
var userAnswer;

function additionQuestion() {
firstNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 11
secondNumber = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 9);
document.getElementById("additionQuestion").innerHTML = + firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber + " = ";
correctAnswer = (firstNumber + secondNumber);
}
```

Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display value in a button, by accessing its `value` property.

For example you have a button like this

```
<input type="button" id="correct" />
```

you can display value in it like this:

```
document.getElementById("correct").value = correctAnswer;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line of code to change your button display text:

```
document.getElementById("yourButtonID").innerHTML= correctAnswer;
```

check this for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score -1):

use jquery;

```
var yourVariable = 48;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.your-button').data('answer', 48);

    $('body').on('click', '.your-button', function(e){
        if($(this).data('answer') === yourVariable){
            alert('good answer');
        }else{
            alert('try again');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4rz5L/

Comment: i don't think this answer deserves a down vote.